# How to prevent the flash of conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I have a register/login page where i check for the user id in the redux state, after a successful login or register , the NotFound component flashes before redirecting to the home page.

login page

```
const Login = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
    const userState = useSelector(authState)
    const { isError, isSuccess, message, id, isLoading } = userState
    const handleError = () => {
        showNotification({
            title: "Error ",
            message: `${message}`,
            color: 'red',
            icon: <AlertCircle />,
        })
    }
    const handelSubmit = () => {
        dispatch(login(userInfo))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isError) {
            handleError()
        }
        if (isSuccess) {
            router.push("/")
        }
    }, [isError, isSuccess])

    if (id === null)
        return (
            <LoginComponent />
        )
    else
        return (
            <NotFound/>
        )
}
```

redux slice

```
const initialState = {
    id: null,
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    email: "",
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ""
}

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/login",
    async (userInput: any, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`/api/users/login`, userInput)
            if (response.data) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token))
            }
            return response.data
        } catch (error: any) {
            const message = error.response.data
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
)

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.isSuccess = false
            state.isError = false
            state.message = ""
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
                state.isLoading = true
            })
            .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.isLoading = false
                state.isSuccess = true
                state.id = action.payload.id
                state.first_name = action.payload.first_name
                state.last_name = action.payload.last_name
                state.email = action.payload.email
            })
    })
```

i tried a conditional render for isloading , `if (isLoading) return (<Loading/>)` , but the flashing still happened.
any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: how about instead of else show the error else if isError then show the error

Comment: when isError i show a notification with that error , with the handleError function , i meant not to display the login component when there is no user stored in the redux state , and instead show the Error component

Comment: but I'm guessing on the first go of useeffect isError, isSuccess both ar null or false.  so its going to fall into the else statement and show your error component.  then isSuccess becomes true and it loads that component, hence the flash of the error. don't use the else put some kind of logic in there

Comment: idk , this part works fine , the one with isError and isSuccess , i might`ve miss-represented the issue ,  , i just renamed the component to NotFound  , the flashing problem is  happening because the if-else with the id . NotFound flashes for a second after a successful login  , id is not null so the NotFound renders for split seconds before the page redirects to home